# how to remove zclip after its copied to clipboard?

Tags: jquery, zclip

I need a way to remove the zclip from my button, as its loaded dynamically, and every time I load it it seems to add another instance of zlip and therefore copies multiple times.

I tried zclip('remove') as per the usage guide but no luck:

```
function zclipMe(){
    $('#copySearch').zclip({
       path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
       copy: function () {
            return $(this).prev('.cvl0').text();
       },
       afterCopy: function(){
            var theText = $(this).prev('.cvl0');
            var thePosition = $(this).prev('.cvl0').position();
            $('.copied').text('Copied!').fadeIn(150).delay(1200).fadeOut(200).css({'top': thePosition.top , 'left': thePosition.left , 'width': theText.width()+30 , 'height': theText.height()+30 , 'line-height': theText.height()+ 30 +'px'});
            $(this).zclip('remove');
       }
    });
}
```

as you can see I overlay a box over the text to be copied with the word 'copied!' in to show it has been copied successfully, and this fires multiple times depending on how many times my dynamic button has been loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
i solve removing event
try
first: $('#copySearch').unbind();
and if you need generate again the button